# Getting Perforce client workspace handling automated

Tags: perforce

I am trying to automate access to Perforce via it's command line utility.
Creating a new client workspace with `p4 client` and syncing works ok.

Now I am allowing users to overwrite *user*, *host*, *port*, *stream*, *revision*.
From the docs it is not clear to me when I have to execute which commands to get the client workspace files in sync with an edited client workspace spec.

What I currently do is once `p4 client` is through search for

```
Client mymachine not changed
```

in stdout and do a `p4 sync -f` should the message not appear.

Is there a better or more sane way to do this?

I tried executing e.g. `p4 sync -s` in hope that it would fail should local data be deleted but it seems that I misunderstood the option?

Comment: It seems to me that you are making work hard on yourself. If you edit your client workspace spec, all you should have to do is an ordinary `p4 sync`. You shouldn't need to pass the `-f` nor `-s` flags. Can you provide a more exact example of why a simple `p4 sync` isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me how this relates to your question about workspaces:

> Now I am allowing users to overwrite user, host, port, stream,
>   revision.

since only one of those is a property of a workspace.  I'm going to disregard that statement for now but if it was significant I'd encourage you to post a follow-up clarifying what you mean by "overwriting" each of these properties.

To your question:

> From the docs it is not clear to me when I have to execute which
>   commands to get the client workspace files in sync with an edited
>   client workspace spec.

If the client **View** is updated, all you need to do is:

```
p4 sync
```

If the client **Root** is updated, or any of the other options that globally affect how files are written to the workspace, such as **allwrite** or **modtime**, you will need to re-sync the entire client.  Ideally this is done by doing:

```
p4 sync #none
```

**prior** to changing the workspace in one of these ways.  The other option would be to do something like the following sequence:

```
p4 sync #none
p4 sync
p4 clean
```

to make sure that everything is rewritten, and that any stragglers (e.g. anything that the "sync #none" couldn't locate because the Root had changed but that are still mapped in the client view) are removed from the workspace.

> I tried executing e.g. p4 sync -s in hope that it would fail should
>   local data be deleted but it seems that I misunderstood the option?

Deleting local data is a separate issue from editing the client spec, but for that the command you want is `p4 clean` rather than `p4 sync` -- you use `sync` to tell the server you want it to send you new revisions, you use `clean` to bring your workspace back in line with what the server already sent you.

The recommended/supported workflow is to always use p4 commands to manipulate the read-only files in your workspace -- so if you want to delete a local file, use either `p4 sync FILE#none` (to remove it from your workspace but not affect the depot) or `p4 delete FILE` (to open it for delete so that it will be deleted for everyone when you submit).